# Реализация событий в проекте на Kohana 3.3

Tags: php, события, kohana

В новом проекте на kohana 3.3 возникла необходимость реализовать события и их обработку. Туплю. Не могу понять как спроектировать.

Немного кода:

```
class EventManager {

    private static $_instance;
    private $events;

    /**
     *
     * @return EventManager
     */
    public static function Instance()
    {
        if (self::$_instance == NULL)
        {
            self::$_instance = new EventManager();
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }

    private function __construct()
    {
        $this->events = new SplObjectStorage();
    }

    public function attach(Event $event)
    {
        $this->events->attach($event);
    }

    public function detach(Event $event)
    {
        $this->events->detach($event);
    }

    public function notify(Event $event = NULL)
    {
        if ($event === NULL)
        {
            foreach ($this->events as $event)
            {
                $event->notify();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $event->notify();
        }

        return;
    }

}

class Event {

    private $sender;
    private $type;
    private $params = array();
    private $handlers;

    function __construct($sender, $type, array $params = NULL)
    {
        $this->sender   = $sender;
        $this->type     = $type;
        $this->params   = $params;
        $this->handlers = new SplObjectStorage();
        EventManager::Instance()->attach($this);
    }

    public function getSender()
    {
        return $this->sender;
    }

    public function getType()
    {
        return $this->type;
    }

    public function getParams()
    {
        return $this->params;
    }

    public function addHandler(EventHandler $handler)
    {
        $this->handlers->attach($handler);
        return $this;
    }

    public function removeHandler(EventHandler $handler)
    {
        $this->handlers->detach($handler);
        return $this;
    }

    public function notify()
    {
        foreach ($this->handlers as $handler)
        {
            $handler->update($this);
        }
    }

}

class EventHandler {

    public function update(Event $event)
    {

    }

}
```

И вот допустим я хочу создать событие beforeGetTitle в модели в какой-нибудь и написать для него обработчик. Сейчас приходится в модели создавать поле для события, в конструкторе его определять и там же навешивать обработчика. Что-то вроде:

```
class Model_Pages_Page extends ORM_Searchable {

    ...

    private $getTitleEvent;

    public function __construct($id = NULL)
    {
        $this->getTitleEvent = new Event($this, get_called_class());
        $this->getTitleEvent->addHandler(new Model_Pages_Page_Handler());
        parent::__construct($id);
    }

    public function getTitle()
    {
        EventManager::Instance()->notify($this->getTitleEvent);
        return $this->get('title');
    }
}
```

Мне в этой реализации всё ненравится. Гугл не подсказал ничего приятного. Вопрос: куда смотреть? Или может среди Вас есть те, кто создавал подобный велосипед?

Answer (score 1):

Мозг включился. Сделал сам всё. Если кому понадобится - обращайтесь=)

Принцип использования прост до невозможности.

```
Event::factory($name, $sender, array $param = NULL)
   ->addHandler($h1)
   ->addHandler($h2)
   ....
   ->addHandler($hN);
```

И сигнал наступления события:

```
Event::run($name);
```